# Someone's Google account under my domain, how to ask for removal?

Tags: google-workspace, google-account, domain

I have a domain and that domain is mine since 2011.

But when I bought it I noticed that there was a previous owner from the emails I was getting.

I recovered his Google account to leave a message to himself on his "Orkut/Google+", asking him to change his email address from my domain to somewhere else.

Yet as of today, the guy still has accounts under my domains, and a few hours ago he re-re-recovered his Google account (proving he is still active and using that account).

Since I already warned him a few years ago, how can I get rid of this guy since he is getting me tons of spam under my mailboxes?

The easy procedure would be to recover his account's passwords, and delete them. But Google accounts are not anymore that simple to recover. I can't recover it from its own email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your domain administrator account, and delete his user (if it's there).

Also set the option to not forward all otherwise-undelivered emails to your administrator account.    After you do this, all messages to his account will bounce.

Comment: Yes, i could simply reject messages coming from his_name@mydomain, but i still don't want him to use my domain for himself. There are many good reasons to do so like to deny him a chance to impersonate me. After all he can talk with someone as if he was really the owner of my domain, and people trust what google says.
PS: Today received more subscriptions he made...

Comment: If someone wants to lie to other people and mailing list, and say that their email address is    theirName@yourDomain.com   then there is nothing you can do in the on-line world to stop them.   Maybe you could get a court order for harassment (or something) - but only if you can track down who the person is in real life.   Good luck with that.

Comment: While not a completely good solution, you're probably right.
I has hopping for the existence of some sort of form to report this cases to Google, but it doesn't seems to exist...